# Deploy failed - missing depedencies When i am using annotations

Tags: jboss, dependencies, singleton, wildfly

i am not so familiar with ejb. I had hard time to set up realm authorization at wildfly, (13) all the time i had same error:

```
  20:33:55,037 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "RaportGeneratorEE-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.security.security-domain.exampleApplicationDomain"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"RaportGeneratorEE-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.ProgrammaticScheduler.CREATE is missing [jboss.security.security-domain.exampleApplicationDomain]"]
```

}
After this i have removed @Singleton Annotation from "ProgrammaticScheduler" and with out  it my realm authentication works well. But than my scheduler doesnt work at all. When i remove lane with

exampleApplicationDomain

Scheduler works, realm doesnt.  Where is the point? This two componenst dont have any common classes.. (well.. i dont know about any). Any one have some ideas? I have seen many familiar problems here but almost all of them were about missing or wrong line in standalone.xml.

Ps. I had another class with @stateless annotation and this class was in error too, but i didnt need it and jsut removed it. Full error log, standalone, jboss-web.xml below. Hope some will find solution

standalone.xml

```
<security-domains>
            <security-domain name="ApplicationDomain" default-realm="ApplicationRealm" permission-mapper="default-permission-mapper">
                <realm name="ApplicationRealm" role-decoder="groups-to-roles"/>
                <realm name="local"/>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="ManagementDomain" default-realm="ManagementRealm" permission-mapper="default-permission-mapper">
                <realm name="ManagementRealm" role-decoder="groups-to-roles"/>
                <realm name="local" role-mapper="super-user-mapper"/>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="jdbcdomain" default-realm="jdbcRealm">
                <realm name="jdbcRealm"/>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="exampleDbSD" default-realm="exampleDbRealm" permission-mapper="default-permission-mapper">
                <realm name="exampleDbRealm" role-decoder="groups-to-roles"/>
            </security-domain>
        </security-domains>
```

ProgrammaticScheduler

```
  @Singleton
    public class ProgrammaticScheduler {



@Schedule(hour="20", minute="33")
public void removeExpiredSearches() throws IOException{
    System.out.println("Kick off!");  

        }

   @Timeout()
   public void onTimeout(Timer timer){


  }
}
```

Error log

```
    20:33:34,908 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.8.5.Final
20:33:36,349 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.4.2.Final
20:33:36,373 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.3.2.Final
20:33:36,662 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 13.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 5.0.0.Final) starting
20:33:40,940 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
20:33:41,000 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 17) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
20:33:41,004 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 7) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.3.3.Final
20:33:41,220 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found RaportGeneratorEE-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called RaportGeneratorEE-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war.dodeploy
20:33:41,324 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
20:33:41,409 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-8) XNIO version 3.6.3.Final
20:33:41,421 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-8) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.6.3.Final
20:33:41,674 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
20:33:41,683 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
20:33:41,666 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYTX0013: The node-identifier attribute on the /subsystem=transactions is set to the default value. This is a danger for environments running multiple servers. Please make sure the attribute value is unique.
20:33:41,677 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) WFLYRS0016: RESTEasy version 3.5.1.Final
20:33:41,682 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=5.0.2.Final
20:33:41,705 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
20:33:41,718 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ee] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) WFLYEE0119: The system property 'ee8.preview.mode' is NOT set to 'true'. For provided EE 8 APIs where the EE 8 version of the API differs from what is supported in EE 7, the EE 7 variant of the API will be used. Support for this setting will be removed once all EE 8 APIs are provided and certified.
20:33:41,737 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
20:33:41,743 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
20:33:41,818 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 2.0.9.Final starting
20:33:41,863 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.4)
20:33:41,885 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.4.9.Final)
20:33:41,932 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
20:33:42,046 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
20:33:42,056 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
20:33:42,419 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path 'C:\Users\Wiki\Downloads\wildfly-13.0.0.Final\wildfly-13.0.0.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
20:33:42,886 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 core threads with 64 task threads based on your 4 available processors
20:33:42,904 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 64 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
20:33:42,913 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
20:33:43,056 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.7.Final
20:33:43,060 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
20:33:43,101 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
20:33:43,112 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYPAT0050: WildFly Full cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
20:33:43,226 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYDM0111: Keystore C:\Users\Wiki\Downloads\wildfly-13.0.0.Final\wildfly-13.0.0.Final\standalone\configuration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
20:33:43,236 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Users\Wiki\Downloads\wildfly-13.0.0.Final\wildfly-13.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments
20:33:43,265 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "mysql" (runtime-name: "mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar")
20:33:43,271 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "RaportGeneratorEE-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name: "RaportGeneratorEE-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")
20:33:43,301 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
20:33:43,345 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
20:33:44,142 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
20:33:44,619 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
20:33:44,801 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.2.1.Final (Apache CXF 3.2.4.jbossorg-1) 
20:33:45,530 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
20:33:45,536 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver (version 5.1)
20:33:45,705 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar_com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver_5_1
20:33:45,706 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1
20:33:45,736 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/MysqlXADS]
20:33:45,745 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/examplePostgresDS]
20:33:47,033 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-1) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Gaina' 9.2.4.Final
20:33:48,039 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
20:33:52,002 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in /C:/Users/Wiki/Downloads/wildfly-13.0.0.Final/wildfly-13.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/RaportGeneratorEE-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/serializer-2.7.2.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
20:33:52,007 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry xercesImpl.jar in /C:/Users/Wiki/Downloads/wildfly-13.0.0.Final/wildfly-13.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/RaportGeneratorEE-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
20:33:52,007 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in /C:/Users/Wiki/Downloads/wildfly-13.0.0.Final/wildfly-13.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/RaportGeneratorEE-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
20:33:52,007 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry serializer.jar in /C:/Users/Wiki/Downloads/wildfly-13.0.0.Final/wildfly-13.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/RaportGeneratorEE-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
20:33:53,000 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment RaportGeneratorEE-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
20:33:53,923 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-3) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.3.6.Final
20:33:54,036 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'ProgrammaticScheduler' in deployment unit 'deployment "RaportGeneratorEE-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"' are as follows:

    java:global/RaportGeneratorEE-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ProgrammaticScheduler!czesak.raportgenerator.service.ProgrammaticScheduler
    java:app/RaportGeneratorEE-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ProgrammaticScheduler!czesak.raportgenerator.service.ProgrammaticScheduler
    java:module/ProgrammaticScheduler!czesak.raportgenerator.service.ProgrammaticScheduler
    ejb:RaportGeneratorEE-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ProgrammaticScheduler!czesak.raportgenerator.service.ProgrammaticScheduler
    java:global/RaportGeneratorEE-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ProgrammaticScheduler
    java:app/RaportGeneratorEE-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ProgrammaticScheduler
    java:module/ProgrammaticScheduler

20:33:54,485 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
20:33:54,490 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver (version 5.1)
20:33:54,500 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver (version 8.0)
20:33:54,539 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-7) WELD-000900: 3.0.4 (Final)
20:33:54,721 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = RaportGeneratorEE-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war_com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver_5_1
20:33:54,722 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = RaportGeneratorEE-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1
20:33:54,724 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = RaportGeneratorEE-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war_com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver_8_0
20:33:55,037 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "RaportGeneratorEE-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.security.security-domain.exampleApplicationDomain"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"RaportGeneratorEE-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.ProgrammaticScheduler.CREATE is missing [jboss.security.security-domain.exampleApplicationDomain]"]
}
20:33:55,057 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "mysql" (runtime-name : "mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar")
20:33:55,058 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "RaportGeneratorEE-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name : "RaportGeneratorEE-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")
20:33:55,064 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.security.security-domain.exampleApplicationDomain (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RaportGeneratorEE-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.ProgrammaticScheduler.CREATE] 
WFLYCTL0448: 225 additional services are down due to their dependencies being missing or failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is need to add aplication-security-domain (using security-domain) in ejb3 services:

```
subsystem=ejb3/application-security-domain=exampleApplicationDomain:add(security-domain=exampleDbSD)
```